# Sending Email populated by google sheets

Tags: email, google-apps-script

Our Engineering Department has a request form on Google that our company uses to notify us of projects and other issues that need attending. The requests are assigned a project lead in our weekly meeting. I'm trying to write a script that will populate an email using data from the spreadsheet the form is driving to notify both the requester and the project lead so that they can contact each other directly instead of email everyone in the Engineering Group for updates. I tried splicing two different codes to achieve this as I was unable to find code I could easily adapt to fit our goal. I have listed the links below to the codes I used to write what I have.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ToKh2JLQYs

The code tells me "Invalid email:" and highlights MailApp.sendEmail, even with real email addresses. Can anyone help? I haven't written any code since high school web design. We are considering using this form of notification in a few of our other departments as well. Assuming I get this version to work.

```
function SendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  //First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2;   //Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:L3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 12)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var Data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var requestername = row[1]; // Second column
    var emailAddr = row[2]; // Third column
    var requestspecifics = row[5]; // Sixth column
    var projectlead = row[6]; // Seventh column
    var projectleademail = ""; // Tenth Column
    else if (projectlead == "Tom Smith") {projectleademail = "tom@fakeemail.com";}
    else if (projectlead == "Dick Smith") {projectleademail = "dick@fakeemail.com";}
    else if (projectlead == "Harry Smith") {projectleademail = "harry@fakeemail.com";}
    else if (projectlead == "none") {projectleademail = null;}
    var emailSent = row[12];  // Last column
    if (emailSent !=EMAIL_SENT) { // Prevents sending duplicates
    var myheader = "Minor Engineering Projects Requests";
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to:emailAddr,
        subject:myheader
        body:requestername + ", \n\n + requestspecifics + " \n\nThe request you
        submitted, listed above, has been assigned to " + projectlead + ". \nPlease
        contact this person with any concerns. \n\nThank You, \n\nEngineering",
        cc:projectlead]);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i,12).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the code above was an exact copy/paste of your actual script but if it was it has a lot of syntax errors that I (hopefully) corrected, please give it a try, it should work if the structure of your spreadsheet is right...

```
function SendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  //First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2;   //Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:L3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 12)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var Data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var requestername = row[1]; // Second column
    var emailAddr = row[2]; // Third column
    var requestspecifics = row[5]; // Sixth column
    var projectlead = row[6]; // Seventh column
    var projectleademail = ""; // Tenth Column
    if (projectlead == "Tom Smith") {projectleademail = "tom@fakeemail.com";}
    else if (projectlead == "Dick Smith") {projectleademail = "dick@fakeemail.com";}
    else if (projectlead == "Harry Smith") {projectleademail = "harry@fakeemail.com";}
    else if (projectlead == "none") {projectleademail = null;}
    var emailSent = row[12];  // Last column
    if (emailSent !="EMAIL_SENT") { // Prevents sending duplicates
    var myheader = "Minor Engineering Projects Requests";
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to:emailAddr,
        subject:myheader,
        body:requestername + ", \n\n" + requestspecifics + " \n\nThe request you"+
        "submitted, listed above, has been assigned to " + projectlead +
        ". \nPlease contact this person with any concerns. \n\nThank You, \n\nEngineering",
        cc:projectlead});
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i,12).setValue("EMAIL_SENT");
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```